# How to detect one chessboard corner?

Tags: matlab, opencv, corner-detection

Given a chessboard image, OpenCV (Matlab and etc.) function can detect chessboard corners very precisely.

Now I have only one chessboard-like corner (Please see two attached images), how can I detect the corner point precisely? Are there any available functions?

If not, Could someone tell me the implementation details of finding chessboard corners in OpenCV? Maybe I can use the similar idea to implement the one-chessboard-corner detection myself.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried the [findChessboardCorners](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) function of OpenCV?

Comment: It doesn't work, cause it is not a chessboard.

Comment: It does not need to be a chess board, anyway, you can try the method that is behind it, the [harris corner detector](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornerharris) and then use [cornerSubPix](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornersubpix) to get a more accurate position of it (subpixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Harris Corner detector](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) to find the corner in the image. If you have the Image Processing Toolbox in MATLAB you can use the `corner()` function to detect the corner: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corner.html

MATLAB code to detect the corner:

```
image = imread('E8UD1.png');
imageGray  = rgb2gray(image);
C = corner(imageGray);
imshow(imageGray);
hold on;
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r*');
```

**Update after comment**

The `corner()` function does a decent job in detecting the corners but you're right you do get outliers, I would instead recommend a more elaborate algorithm, it's called [Shi-Tomasi Corner Detector & Good Features to Track](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html)

Here are the results I get when I run the new image:

[image]

Still not perfect but you can play around with the parameters for the `goodFeaturesToTrack()` function

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

filename = 'ddNNZ.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,1,0.01,10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

cv2.imwrite('result.png',img)
```

Comment: The corner() function can detect the intersection point in the very high quality image. However, for the regular image (I added a new image), the corner function cannot detect the intersection point. Actually, it detects two corner points between the intersection region of the two black rectangle. Maybe we need a method to merge the two corner points.

Comment: That's strange because when I run the image through the `corner()` function I get a single pixel returned, which you can draw using this line of code `plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r*');` assuming C contains the X and Y coordinates for the corner. I'll edit the answer with a little bit of code.

Comment: Please test new images I just added. Those images are images taken by cameras. The previous image is the perfect image that generated by function in the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your method and read the goodFeaturesToTrack(). You method may solve the given two images. However, it is not a solution for all such images. We need design a new method by understanding the idea of chessboard corner detection algorithm. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp

Comment: This is a good answer that goes through the inner workings of the `findChessboardCorners()` function - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/how-does-opencv-find-chessboard-corners

Comment: I would also recommend you do some pre-processing such as [blurring](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) the image to remove noise and maybe do some sort of [contrast enhancement](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html), then use an [Adaptive Threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to create the binary image. I hope this helps if you think this is enough to point you in the right direction please mark this question as answered.

Comment: I think findChessboardCorners requires a minimal chessboard size to be 3x3. In OP's question, he has only 1x1 chessboard.